# How to fix position glitching in css?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to know how can I fix a `<div>` glitching while changing a div content using `.load()`?

The div CSS is:

```
#MyDiv{
  position: fixed;
  z-index: 9;
  bottom: 0;
  transition: transform 200ms;
}
```

whenever a div content changes, the div starts glitching and changing its position then it comes back to normal.

I think that what's causing the problem is the phone layout, that glitch happens only on phones

Comment: do you have a transform on any of the div’s parents?

Comment: I've it on the content div `MyDiv`

Comment: can you show the css where you have the tranform

Comment: `transition: transform 200ms;`

Comment: sorry, i meant transform like transform: translat3d(...)

Comment: no, I don't have that kind of code, but there's `transform: translateX(100%);`

Comment: ok. i think it would be better to show the rest of your css but that is directly related to this div

Comment: oh, and on which browser(s) does it happen?

Comment: Umm, All of the CSS is related to the div, but you can check it on **https://enderadel.cf**, the div is named **EnderBar**, and its CSS is in the file **assets/css/EnderDesign.css**

Comment: try and test it on Chrome (Using phone display in the developer tools, or any phone)

Comment: i meant to show the css in the parent and its parent and so on. If you try firefox does it have the same problem? position can be tricky. I have notices sometimes it does not work if something was tranformed. once i had to change a div to display:absolute

Comment: I've also looked into the page but I am unable to find any CSS rule with "transition: transform". Also, the animations there look to be working as designed. Are those animations the ones that you do not want to have? Here is what I see: https://gph.is/g/EGRenx1

Comment: I've removed the down bar (**EnderBar**) when you go into a page that has an input, so the glitch won't happen, anyway thanks for your help